# Why is there two instances of "Okular" and how do I get rid of the other one?

Tags: gnome, software-center, snap, 20.04, okular

I have noticed that when I do a program search in Ubuntu 20.04, there are two instances of the program Okular. One with an icon and one that has the generic application icon (gear). I installed Okular from Ubuntu Software. This doesn't seem to happen with other applications that I have also installed from Ubuntu Software. I'd search this on Google myself but I'm not quite sure how to describe this issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

I should note that this was a fresh install.

Links to relevant screenshots... (I don't have 10 reputation yet to embed images)

**Two icons in search**

[image: Two icons in search]

**Output of `snap list`**

[image: Output of <code>snap list</code>]

**Output of `apt policy okular`**

[image: Output of <code>apt policy okular</code>]

Comment: Okay, so you seem to have the snap version and not the deb version. That still doesn't explain why you see two icons. I guess you can figure out which is the real icon and just use that in case no one comes up with a good explanation.

Comment: I added the images for you. BTW, for the future, please don't provide terminal output as images. It is difficult for responders to use part of the output in their answers or in requests for clarification. Instead, copy and paste the relevant output here using this site's [markdown formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: I'll bookmark that and make sure that I will do that next time. Thank you for the edit.

Comment: Hmmm! I installed the okular snap in Xubuntu 20.04 and see the same two icons as you do. Both are functional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOTE: *This answer works for the okular snap in Xubuntu 20.04, and in Ubuntu 20.04*

After installing `okular` as a snap package, I see two icons in the Whisker Menu launcher: one seems to represent `okular` and the other is generic but both show the same tooltip (Universal document viewer).

[image: Two okular icons]

I ran `locate -i okular | grep -i desktop` to identify the corresponding .desktop files. (*Ubuntu users may need to install the `mlocate` package to access the `locate` command.*) There were several hits but

```
/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/okular_okular.desktop
/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/okular_org.kde.okular.desktop
```

are relevant.

- I copied these two .desktop files over to `~/.local/share/applications`. The `applications` subfolder may not exist originally in which case it should be created.
- I edited both files to remove extra names, generic names, and comments and then compared the two files.

```
dkb@dkb-xubuFF:~/.local/share/applications$ ls
okular_okular.desktop  okular_org.kde.okular.desktop
dkb@dkb-xubuFF:~/.local/share/applications$ diff *.desktop
7,8c7
< Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/okular_okular.desktop /snap/bin/okular %U
< Icon=/snap/okular/98/usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps/okular.png
---
> Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/okular_org.kde.okular.desktop /snap/bin/okular %U
12d10
< 
dkb@dkb-xubuFF:~/.local/share/applications$
```

As you can see from the output,

- the `Exec=` lines of both .desktop files launch `/snap/bin/okular %U`
- one .desktop file, okular_org.kde.okular.desktop, is missing the line beginning with `Icon` and that explains the "generic" icon in the application menu.
- since both .desktop files seem to be equivalent, we can just "hide" the one which shows the generic icon by adding `NoDisplay=true` as the last line to that .desktop file.

Now, there's just the one "okular" when one types `oku` in a launcher's search bar:

[image: Just one okular]

**Note**:

- none of the operations above need the user to be `root` or to invoke `sudo`
- modifications made to .desktop files in `~/.local/share/applications` will survive updates of the parent packages.

---

[A bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=420694) has been filed.

Comment: I'm going to try this now and report back. Many thanks.

Comment: Why not let the two icons be? Then, use one whenever you want to run `Okular`?

Answer (score 0):

You guys are seeing that other part of okular because it conflicts the already present Evince PDF Reader package in Ubuntu and all the derived distros. If you save that other icon in utilities and remove Okular.. you will see Evince PDF reader icon appears at that place.

hope this helps
Scoop