# When I install KolourPaint why does it have two icons? How can I fix it?

Tags: 20.04

[image]

Just updated to 20.04 and tired to install KolourPaint, but it installs two icons. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: If you've installed it as a snap package, see if https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230835/why-is-there-two-instances-of-okular-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-other-one/1231203#1231203 helps you.

Comment: I just installed it myself as a snap on Ubuntu 20.04. Looks just like what you see and in the linked question. If you have difficulty following the solution, let us know where exactly you're getting stuck.

Comment: I followed the instructions but for some reason locate couldn't find the files and shows a .desktop.json file in another directory. So I manually went to the same directory in the other thread and followed the rest of the instructions. Glad to say that it worked! Thanks for your help!