# How can I get snap icons to use my icon theme and not change back after updates?

Tags: gnome, icons, themes, snap

Snap .desktop files are stored in `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications`.  The icons used there have a hard coded path.  I can change the path to just the application name so that it uses my gnome icon theme.  But when the snap updates, it recreates the .desktop file, thus undoing my change.  How I can make it so the icons never change?

Comment: Having copies in `~/.local/share/applications/` that you can modify should help: [example](https://askubuntu.com/q/1230835/248158)